# How to vertically align an image and right text inside a container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make this layout on bootstrap where I have 3 centered divs along with the icon and right text, but I am getting a vertical layout and long space between image and text. how can I make it horizontal and fix my long space?
[desire_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zHpf.png)

```
        



<div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="steps">
                    <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" style="height: 80px;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2 class="steps__title">How It Works</h2>
                    <p>demo</p>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="steps">
                    <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" style="height: 80px;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2 class="steps__title">How It Works</h2>
                    <p>demo</p>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="steps">
                    <img src="https://code.google.com/images/developers.png" style="height: 80px;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                    <h2 class="steps__title">How It Works</h2>
                    <p>demo</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if helps, but try to add this style in your parent div:

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: row;
```

Also, increase some space between them.

Maybe this article can help you:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/